# Disable SCK temporarily to save power

Tags: power, spi, sd-card

for logging of environmental data, I am using a MicroSD card adapter (no brand name, eBay, China) and a 4GB Intenso SD card. I want to read data and write it to the SD card once every 10 minutes. Power consumption needs to be as low as possible.

Between the measurement points, I switch off the power supply to my sensor and SD card adapter using an NPN transistor (BC547B, 2N3904, 2SC945) and put my controller to sleep using [jeelib](http://jeelabs.org/2011/12/13/developing-a-low-power-sketch/). Everything works fine!

*But* I realized, that even during sleep, still 1mA of current is drawn. This disappears, when I remove the SCK connection between the Arduino and the SD controller. Doesn't sound like a lot, but for my purposes, it's a major concern (when SCK is removed, I'm around 6µA during sleep).

**Is it possible to switch the SCK signal off during sleep to save that last bit of power?**

In case it matters, I am using the SdFat library to write to SD. Initialization is done before each write. I figured, this would be necessary because of the poweroff of 10 minutes. Here's the function:

```
#include <SdFat.h>
const int chipSelect = 10;
String outfilename = "Bienen.log";
```

[...]

```
int writeToFile(String outfilename, String writestring) {

  SdFat SD;
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    error_signal();
#endif
  } else {
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("card initialized.");
#endif
  }

File outfile = SD.open(outfilename.c_str(), FILE_WRITE);
#ifdef DEBUG
  Serial.println(outfile);
#endif
  if (outfile) {
    outfile.println(writestring);
    outfile.close();
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("Wrote successfully.");
    ok_signal();
#endif
    return 0;
  } else {
#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("Writing failed.");
    error_signal();
#endif
    return 1;
  }
}
```

ok_signal() and error_signal() are merely functions to flash an LED.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for your reply! I tried the code snippets

```
SPCR &= ~_BV(SPE)
```

and

```
SPCR |= _BV(SPE)
```

at the appropriate places, although I did not understand them. There was, however, no change in power consumption - SCK still seems to run.

I could not adapt the physical changes detailed in the suggested wordpress article, as the adapter there is quite different from [my microSD adapter](http://robojax.com/products/images/ELE_SDCARDUI_176.jpg), and I know too little about hardware to adapt the author's suggestions. It looks and sounds quite promising though ...

Thanks for your time! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll have to disable SPI (`SPCR &= ~_BV(SPE)`), and set the pin to LOW. Then when writing, re-enable SPI (`SPCR |= _BV(SPE)`).

Comment: Also see these posts: https://edwardmallon.wordpress.com/2016/10/27/diy-arduino-promini-data-logger-2016-build-update/ (Section named "The SD Card Adapter"), and https://edwardmallon.wordpress.com/2014/09/22/high-sleep-current-problem-solved/ for a lot of useful low-power information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-visiting the issue, I have found a simple answer:

I set the SPI pins as outputs and inputs respectively:

```
const int chipSelect = 10;
const int MOSIPin = 11;
const int MISOPin = 12;
const int SCKPin = 13;
```

and

```
  pinMode(chipSelect, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MOSIPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MISOPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(SCKPin, OUTPUT);
```

Now, before I power down my machine, I do the following:

```
  SPI.end();
  digitalWrite(SCKPin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(chipSelect, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(MOSIPin, HIGH);
```

Now, the drawn current drops from 1mA to roughly 0,02mA, which is satisfactoy for me!

Thanks for reading!